# Taylor Series & Maclaurin Series

Tags: calculus

$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!} (x-a)^n=f(a)+f'(a) (x-a)+\frac{f''(a)}{2!}(x-a)^2+\frac{f'''(a)}{3!}(x-a)^3+\cdots$$

In order to approximate let's say $\sin(56°)$ do I calculate taking $a$ as $56π/180$ or do I find the Maclaurin series and then take $x$ as $56π/180$?

In short, what do we mean by taking $a$ as $0$?

Comment: Do you really want the sine of $56$ radians, or was $56$ a typo for $56^\circ$?

Answer (score 2):

First, convert to radian, $56 \cdot \frac{\pi }{180} = \frac{14 \pi }{45}$. Now, the Maclaurin of sine of x is

$$ \sin x = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{ (-1)^n x^{2n+1} }{(2n+1)!} $$

Now, $\frac{14 \pi }{45 }$ is close to $0$ (not really), thus for instance one can take

$$ \sin \frac{14 \pi }{45 } \approx \frac{14 \pi }{45 } - (\frac{14 \pi }{45 })^3 / 3! $$

as an approximation. the more terms you take, the better the approximation

Comment: I have understood this, thank you, but if we took $a$ as $56π/180$, what does it mean? In this case all terms are zero. Is it something like taking a value as origin? What if $a$ was $π/6$?